# Xcode - IB Designable: Failed to render and update auto layout (no suitable image found)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, ibdesignable

I am trying to implement a custom UIView from a .xib file which I want to be able to inspect in one of my storyboards. However, I receive a build time error:

> IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for LoginViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): dlopen(App.app, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       App.app: can't map unslidable segment __TEXT to 0x100000000 with size 0x268000

I am using CocoaPods and read that this was due to a bug in version 1.5. I tried some workarounds and a downgrade to 1.4 without any results. I have also tried removing the DerivedData folder and cleaning/rebuilding the project.

My .xib file contains a simple temporary UIView, and this is the corresponding code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ButtonPrimary: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initNib()
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initNib()
        setup()
    }

    func initNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ButtonPrimary.self)
        bundle.loadNibNamed("ButtonPrimary", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(button)
        button.frame = bounds
        button.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Which workarounds have you tried?

I had the same issue and adding this workaround to my Podfile, fixed it for me.  I found this workaround [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606).

```
# Workaround for Cocoapods issue #7606
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

It removes the `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED` and `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` build-settings from your Pods.

Comment: Yeah, I did try that one, as well as a couple of other workarounds. But as I understand, the workarounds only apply to CocoaPods 1.5 so I guess downgrading it would have solved any eventual issues?